ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
I'm having trouble getting a Python string to be correctly interpreted by ctypes.
Here are the steps to reproduce the error:

Create the file shared.c:

#include <stdio.h>

void hello(char *name){
    printf("Hello");
}


Create the file loader.c

void hello(char *name);

void main(){
    hello(char *name);
}


Generates the shared file and named it to test.so
gcc -shared shared.c -o test.so

Create the Python script called reproduce_error.py:


import ctypes

lib_name = './test.so'
lib=ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_name)
init_hello=lib.hello
init_hello.argtypes=[ctypes.c_char_p]
init_hello("Test")


Run the Python script: python reproduce_error.py

The full traceback of the step 5 is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reproduce_error.py", line 8, in <module>
    init_hello('Test')
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type

Does anyone know why this issue occurs or could offer some suggestions on how to resolve it? Thank you!

I tried this solution using wintypes but soon realize that this doesn't generalize to Linux based systems. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.

I tried to create a string buffer with create_string_buffer for utf-8 and latin-1  before to pass the string argument to the function init_hello. Something like:


Step 4 modified:
import ctypes
from ctypes import c_bool

lib_name = './test.so'
lib=ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_name)
init_hello=lib.hello
init_hello.argtypes=[ctypes.c_char_p]
init_hello.restype = c_bool
s = ctypes.create_string_buffer(lib_name.encode("utf-8"))
init_hello('Test')

but that didn't work as well and I got the same error.
The string in Python, "Test", is not being correctely interpreted by ctypes.c_char_p. Therefore, I expect to find the correct way to interface between Python and C.

Note that the restype for void should be None not c_bool

A c_char_p argument expects a byte string. Use init_hello(b'Test').
Alternatively, use the C wchar_t* type and ctypes c_wchar_p type and Unicode strings will work.

Thank you! c_wchar_p worked nicely.
